# how to read a jms queue from a non hosted java application?

Tags: jms

I'm trying to read messages from a jms queue created in "Sun App Server" from a non-hosted application (console app) but I get the following error:

```
NoInitialContextException
Cannot instantiate class: javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory
```

with this code:

```
Properties env = new Properties( );
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory");
InitialContext jndi = new InitialContext(env);
```

and I have referenced the j2ee.jar library that contains the class but certainly, the class is an interface.

Can I access the queue from a non-hosted application??

Answer (score 1):

Aitor;

When you say "Sun App Server", I'm not sure what that means, but I will assume it is Glassfish.

There are 2 separate steps to acquiring remote JMS resources.

1. You need to create a remote JNDI connection which requires a valid InitialContextFactory class name.
2. Once you have a the connection, you can look up the TopicConnectionFactory.

For item #1, [this link](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#nonJavaEEwebcontainerRemoteEJB) demonstrates how to make a remote JNDI connection.
For item #2, once you have a JNDI context, you will also need to know the JNDI name of the TopicConnectionFactory which will look something like:

```
TopicConnectionFactory tcf = (TopicConnectionFactory) jndi.lookup("jms/TopicConnectionFactory");
```

One aspect you need to keep in mind is that the **j2ee.jar** library contains the generic Java EE *interfaces* for the JMS classes, but you will also need a library in your classpath that contain the JMS implementation *concrete classes*. This also goes for the JNDI connection. This [tutorial](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/tutorial-starting-with-glassfish-and-jms-part-2/) provides a concise list as:

**Applicationserver JNDI Lookup**

- /lib/appserv-rt.jar
- /lib/appserv-admin.jar
- /lib/javaee.jar /lib/j2ee.jar

**Client Lib**

- /imq/lib/jms.jar
- /imq/lib/imq.jar
- /imq/lib/imqutil.jar
- /lib/install/applications/jmsra/jmsra.jar